# How do I break two form fields into two lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function v(id){
    return $("#"+id).val();
} 
var myToken = v("token");
var myData = {
    Address: v("Address") +'\n'+ v("building")
};
```

and it displays values as follows:

> > 236 Adams way bulding 19

In the example above, Address is 236 Adams way and buidling is building 19.

I would like to have the values display as:

> > 236 Adams way
> >     Building 19

How do I modify the script above to get the result we desire?

Comment: Wrap them in <p> tags? Add a <br />? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, newlines don't show up. You'd need to insert a `<br/>` in your output text:

```
function v(id){
    return $("#"+id).val();
} 
var myToken = v("token");
var myData = {
    Address: v("Address") +'<br/>'+ v("building")
};
```

Comment: Experts, is this such a horrible question to give me a -4 markdown? @Joeytjet50, I tried that and got an error. That's why I changed to \n. This forum is merciless AND GREAT at same time. WOW!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, just to clarify. Anyway, usually when you get an error, it's best to include the things you tried, and the error you got. I recommend you read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions. Anyway, what error did you get?

Comment: @Joeytle50, I get this when tested with firebug: `ReferenceError: oTable is not defined`

 If I change to \n, I get the result I showed in my original post and no errors

Comment: @ChidiOkeh It looks like you're trying to fix a symptom with the change to `\n`, not the problem itself. Usually firebug also shows a line number (which is clickable). If you check there, perhaps you can find which problem is causing this error. The use of `<br/>` for new lines in HTML is correct though.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh PS: perhaps [this link](http://xyproblem.info/) could be useful too for asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the `\n` to `<br/>`